# Meteor: record in db updating, but data not changing on screen

Tags: mongodb, meteor, modulus.io

Here's a simplified version of what I have in one of my templates:

```
{{#each dataRecord}}

{{#if editingNow}}

  <tr class="dataRow">
    <td><button class="updateRecord" id="{{this._id}}">SAV</button></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="{{this._id}}" value="{{this.f}}"></td></td>
  </tr>

  {{else}}

  <tr class="dataRow">
    <td><button class="edit" id="{{this._id}}">EDIT</button></td>
    <td>{{this.f}}</td> 
    <td><button class="deleteRecord" id="{{this._id}}">DEL</button> </td>
  </tr>

{{/if}}

{{/each}}
```

editingNow returns the value of boolean session variable which starts out as false.  So when the page loads, the user sees the value of the 'f' field for each record and the EDIT button.  The EDIT button flips the session variable to true and then the data is shown using an input element.  The user can edit the data and click the button, which is now a SAVE button.  That button updates the record using the _id and flips the session variable back to false.

The works as far as editing the data goes -- the record is definitely getting updated.  I can check the value in the console and see that it has been changed.  But the data that gets displayed in the table reverts back to the original value.  I can see the change displayed in that field very briefly and then it flips back.  Even weirder, if I click the EDIT button again, the table still displays the old value.  The only way to see the updated data in that field is to restart the app.

This problem never occurred when I was using my local mongo db or when I was linking to my database on meteor.com.  This has only started happening since I moved my app to modulus.io.  Any ideas?

**UPDATE**
Although I could not figure out what was causing the reactive update problem in the template, with Ethaan's help, I was able to get a better understanding of the issue and find a work-around, so I've accepted the answer and hopefully we will get to the bottom of this eventually.

Comment: Go to you `project > logs` and check if you get some logs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you have some `allow/deny` problems maybe?

Try with

```
Collection.allow({
 insert:function(){return true;},
 remove:function(){return true;},
 update:function(){return true;},
})
```

Or check the connection with the database is succefull, go to the [admin panel on modulus](https://my.modulus.io/database/yourDBId)

**Option 2**

Clean the database and make a dummy insert on the server side.

First on the meteor shell run `meteor reset`.

**OR** If you have the application is on modulus.io use the `mongo shell`, and use this piece of code.

```
db.getCollectionNames().forEach(function(name) {
  if (name.indexOf('system.') === -1) {
    db.getCollection(name).drop();
  }
})
```

Now when you are sure the database is *empty*, put this on the server side.

```
//Server Code.
    Meteor.startup(function(){
      if(Collection.find().count() == 0){
        Collection.insert({serverInsert:"test from server"},function(err,result){
         if(!err){
          console.log("insert succefull")
        }
     })
    }
  })
```

Comment: At this point, I am still using the insecure package, so there shouldn't be any possibility of allow / deny, errors, is that right?  Sorry, I should have mentioned that.  And I'm not sure I'm understanding the reason for emptying the database and trying to insert from the server.  The update to the record is definitely happening and it is correct, but the reactive template does not show the change, which, as I said, has never happened before.  After reading this answer, I added a method on the server to do the update, and this method also works, but the template is still showing the old value.

Comment: If you see the data updated on the console but not on the template, this helper `dataRecord` return the correct database cursor?

Comment: This is very strange.  In the server method that updates the record, I check the result value to see how many fields were updated.  And that result is 1 every time, as it should be.  But then when I do a collection.find() on that ID in the browser console, the record is not updated.  So it's like the publication stop working?  My mini-mongo db never got the update?  What could cause this?

Comment: This only happens on the modulus.io application? can i see the app? give me the link, and check if this is also happening on the local app, check that you have the insecure package and everything its OK, i don't think the publication stop working just like that, you have a typo or something

Comment: Your questions and ideas have helped me to discover that the deployed version doesn't have this problem.  The problem is with my local app when it's connected to the modulus-hosted mongo db.  When it's connected my local mongodb or the one on meteor.com, I don't have the problem.  The shared mongodb instance that I'm using on modulus doesn't allow for the use of oplog tailing.  Could that be it?  If so, I still don't understand why the deployed version works.  So this is an OK workardound for me, but I can direct you to the github source for the app if you would like to see it.  Thanks again.

Comment: Maybe the username you are connecting from the localhost have only readOnly access, thats why you get that, because you are getting the connection with the mongodb on modulus Ok right? you see the documents from the mongodb on the localhost app? yea link me to the github to check it, also it will be nice if you accept/upvote if this help you

Comment: There's only one database user so I don't think that's it.  I definitely see the docs from the hosted db in my console, I just don't receive their updates until I restart the app.  Which makes it seem like my connection is read-only, but I can actually update the docs from the client -- I just don't get the reactive change in the template like I do when I'm connected to my local db or the db on meteor.com (or using the deployed version).  Having some issues with github right now, so I don't have the right version up there, but you haven't heard the last of me, I'm sure!

Comment: put the subscribe inside a `Tracker.autorund(function(){});` on the client side